# How can sum the elements in array in kotlin language?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
package sum

fun sum(a: IntArray): Int {
  return 0
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post your own attempt at a solution when posting homework questions to Stack Overflow. People are happy to help you when you're stuck, but nobody wants to do it for you.

Comment: package sum

fun sum(a: IntArray): Int {
   
    
    for (i in 0..a.index){
        
        sum = i + i
        
        }
    
    return sum 
}

Comment: this is not homework it from kotlin website and this is the link for that   https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Problems/Sum/Sum.kt

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html

Answer (score 16):

There's a built in function to sum an IntArray in Kotlin

```
val numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
val sum = numbers.sum()
```

Or to do it yourself...

```
fun sumArray(array: IntArray): Int{
    var sum = 0
    for(number in array){
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
```

Comment: you are my hero i know it is easy but  i am begineer with kotlin and review with u and stack overflow team :)

Comment: Suggested edit for future readers - shouldn't the function `sumArray` use the `array` argument, rather than `numbers`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`sum`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html) directly:

```
val sum = arrayOf(12, 33).sum()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do it as a stream

```
val sum = arrayOf(7, 9).fold(0) { acc, e -> acc + e }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I prefer

```
array.reduce { acc, l -> acc + l }
```

If you've got an object instead of a primary data for example, you can access it and sumup

Answer (score 0):

```
fun sum(numbers: IntArray) = numbers.sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fold`. The advantage is more freedom with data handling.

For example, if you have nested arrays, and want the sum of the nested array sizes, you can do something like this:

```
val totalSize = array1.fold(0) { acc, i -> acc + i.array2.size }
```

In case of array with just integers:

```
val sum = array.fold(0) { acc, i -> acc + i }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
fun main() {
    val myArray = arrayOf(6, 5, 8, 2, 11, 25)
    var sum = 0
    for (number in myArray) {
        sum += number
    }
    println(sum)
}
```